# Linebreak with DomDocument in a node

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, line-breaks

I'm creating a xml file with the DOMDocument class in php. I want to make a block node for my address, like this:

```
<Address>CompanyName
Street
Place</Address>
```

I have to create the address field like this, because the xml is imported by an other person.

I already tried "\n", "cdata", "< br >" but its also printed. Is there any way to make a line break with DOMDocument in an xml without any additional text?

Or is there maybe an other, better way to do this? (XMLWriter?)

Sorry for my english :) and thanks for help

edit:
if i open it in firefox, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You tried `\n` and it didn't work?

Comment: \n is displayed in the block, but is all on one line

Comment: don't know if this has any influence, but at the end i set formatOutput on true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works just fine. In your internet explorer, right click on the page and then click "view source". The new lines are there.

Comment: i opened in in firefox, and the \n is still there (posted a picture above)

Comment: use double quotes in php. "like\nthis". http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: yes it worked, thanks alot, you saved my day :D i made a stupid mistake ^^

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify whether the newlines should be normalized or preserved you have to set the preserveWhiteSpace option accordingly:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace